# Making Apple style settings view

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make settings in my application like Apple Settings. How can I make settings in such style?

*In my mind I need TableView + custom Cells with Images & Switches, but it’s very difficult way to go. I think that XCode has easier and more standart way to do that*

**Update** I'm talking about creating custom in-app settings view, not about Settings.bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm newbie, so i didn't know how to do ViewController like Apple Settings inside application. Now i know that, so answering on my question.

You can make settings in your application in 2 ways:

1. Make settings via settings.bundle, that settings will appear in Settings.app (not in your app). More at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html.
2. Make UITableViewController and there you can customize cells to appear like native Apple Settings.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in the settings app then you need to look up about settings bundles: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html

If you want to have it look like the settings app but be *within* your app then I'd recommend InAppSettingsKit: http://www.inappsettingskit.com

Comment: If you add your settings to the Settings app, you can launch straight to your app's Settings page by using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]`.

Comment: That's a good point, although if using < iOS 8 then you'll need to do some additional checking

Comment: True. You won't be able to launch to the Settings app on devices < iOS 8. You also won't be able to return to the app from the Settings app on any iOS version. Figured it was worth noting, though. He was pretty unclear about his intended use of this settings screen -- if it's app-instance-specific data, putting it in a static app Settings screen doesn't make sense anyway.